# Stuck on linked list exercise

Tags: c

I wrote this function that creates new nodes.

When I add only one node, the program works but if I add the second node I get a segmentation fault, so clearly the problem lies in the "else" part of the function "add_node()" but I can't figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    char *city;
    struct node *next;
}node;

node *start = NULL;
node *current;

void add_node(char *cityname) {
    node *y = malloc(sizeof(node));
    y->city = cityname;
    y->next = NULL;
    current = start;

    if(start == NULL) {
        start = y;
    } else {
        while (current != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = y;
    }   
}

int main() {
    add_node("Paris");
    add_node("London");

    current = start;

    while(current != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", current->city);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a loop that runs until `current` is NULL ... then you set `current->next` to `y`, but `current` is necessarily NULL.

A simple way to fix it is to change the loop to

```
while (current->next != NULL){
```

I'll also note that you should avoid globals. `current` should be a local variable  and `start` should be a parameter ... and I would just call it `list`, since that's what it represents. `add_node` should return the (possibly new) value of `list`.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
    while (current != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = y;
```

When does the `while` stop? When `current` becomes `null`. Then `current->next` raises a segmentation fault.

You have to stop one short of `NULL`. Compare `current->next` to `NULL`, instead of `current`, so by the time the loop exits you're still pointing to a node.

Answer (score 0):

This loop:

```
while (current != NULL){
    current = current->next;
}
```

Will move throught current until `current == NULL`. Once that happens this line:

```
 current->next = y;
```

will try to deference that NULL, which of course will cause a seg fault. You just wanted:

```
while(!current && current->next != NULL)
```

technically you only need `while(current->next != NULL)` because you do the check for `start`, however IMO it's good practice to check a pointer for NULL like this before you deference it.

Comment: `current = y` will overwrite the iteration variable, without appending the item to the linked list

Comment: " it's good practice to check a pointer for NULL like this before you deference it. " -- It just *was* checked. These sorts of redundant checks are actually very poor practice ... they make the code much harder to read and follow and destroy its abstract nature ... here, there's a loop to find a null `next` pointer, so two null checks in the loop condition makes no logical sense. A guard for an empty list would look like `if (current != NULL) { while (current->next != NULL) { ... }}` but that guard is already there.